# How to design mockups and prototypes for Android Apps? (free solutions / free for students)

Tags: android, mockup

Can you please suggest some free tools for drawing mockups for android apps. TIA:

Comment: Hi Chetan, welcome to UX! This is a Q&A site where you can ask about specific problems that experts can help answer. In your specific case, the best answer is Google (try typing your question there). If you have a question that can only be answered with the help of UX experts, feel free to ask it!

Comment: Hi @Rahul, my purpose of adding this question was to ask expert advice over it only. Like I can obviously search for that in Google. But what I actually wanted was to know what do you guys normally use and in case something is available in free, cos am a student and normally dun have much funds to buy softwares. I guess I framed it wrongly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out answers to similar questions at Stackoverflow:

- [Tools for creating mockups for Android mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5460624/tools-for-creating-mockups-for-android-mobile)
- [GUI Design Tools to mock up iPhone & Android applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/929875/gui-design-tools-to-mock-up-iphone-android-applications)
- [GUI Design/Mockup Design Tool for Android Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4253197/gui-design-mockup-design-tool-for-android-application)